# What are the most important graduate-level (sub)branches of mathematics and their prerequisites?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

As a self learner, sometimes I am really surprised when I find about a branch that I didn't know it existed, and only once I know about it, I find it everywhere and everyone seems to know it and that it's obviously important; the top example being Analysis, for quite some time I just thought it was another way of saying calculus. Another not-so 'obvious' example would be model theory, another representation theory (which I learned about yesterday).

I understand that this could be answered with thousands of topics but I want to know the 'main' ones if such a thing exists. Ideally, I'd like something like [Teach Yourself Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic2017.pdf), or something with a structure similar to that. More simply, I'd be satisfied with just a nested list of branches (e.g. logic) and then some main subbranches (e.g. model theory, set theory, etc) under it with a short description of it.

Comment: [The Mathematics Autodidact's Aid](https://www.ams.org/notices/200510/comm-fowler.pdf) is a classic. It isn't fully comprehensive, though. There are some fields not mentioned there that are very useful at the graduate level, such as functional analysis or model theory.

Comment: IMHO analysis and algebra are the core of mathematics, all other branches are specific developments of analytic and algebraic concepts

Comment: @Masacroso Hmmm, I would put geometry in there too.

Comment: @DonThousand I know, what I said is very arguable. But I mean that, by example, to develop geometry we need algebraic and analytic concepts after all. Same for number theory, and so on. Anyway it is just my point of view

Comment: @Masacroso Hard disagree. Algebra/Analysis was used in geometry only in the past 300-ish years, vs nearly 2000 years of geometric development.

Comment: @Masacroso What about topology?

Comment: @Masacroso what about category theory and related, or foundations?

Comment: You may want to look at [**All the Mathematics You Missed: But Need to Know for Graduate School**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521797071/) by Thomas A. Garrity and Lori Pedersen (2001).